# como pasar un arreglo por js a php

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="verMatch2(this,'<?php echo base64_encode($datosSolicitud['id']);?>','<?php print_r($datosSolicitud); ?>');">
```

quiero pasar `$datosSolicitud` que es un arreglo a un archivo js

```
function verMatch2(elemento,solicitudEmpleo,datosSolicitud){
    $("tr.tmp").remove();
    tmp = $(elemento); fila = tmp.closest('tr');
    $.ajax({
    data: {solicitudEmpleo : solicitudEmpleo,datosSolicitud : datosSolicitud},
        url:   'index.php?accion=verMatch2',
            type:  'post',
        success:  function (data) {
            fila.after("<tr class='tmp'><td colspan='6'>"+data+"</td></tr>");
            $(".loader").fadeOut("fast");
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(parametros);
        },
    });
}
```

luego recibirlo en el controlador pero ¿como hago para enviarlo? si no fuera arreglo uso echo para imprimirlo en la function de javascript.

Comment: Hay muchas preguntas en el sitio sobre cómo pasar variables de JS a PHP y viceversa. Lee [ask] y busca en el sitio, seguro que encontrarás soluciones a lo que quieres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para solucionarlo podrías hacer uso de:

- [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php): Esta funnción convertira el arreglo `PHP` en una cadena equivalente a un objeto `JS`.
- [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php): Esta función toma una cadena y escapa solo aquellos caracteres que pueden provocar que la cadena rompa el `HTML` al imprimir el valor dentro del atributo de un elemento.

#### Solución

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="verMatch2(this,'<?php echo base64_encode($datosSolicitud['id']);?>',<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($datosSolicitud)); ?>);">texto</a>
```

#### Ejemplo

```
<?php
$datosSolicitud = [
    'id'=> 1,
    'algo'=> 'Texto con \'asd\' "dsa"'
];

$json = json_encode($datosSolicitud);
// $json == {"id":1,"algo":"Texto con 'asd' \"dsa\""}

$html = htmlspecialchars($json);
// $html == {&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;algo&quot;:&quot;Texto con 'asd' \&quot;dsa\&quot;&quot;}
```

#### Demo

```js
function verMatch2(el, id, data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="verMatch2(this,'MQ==',{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;algo&quot;:&quot;Texto con 'asd' \&quot;dsa\&quot;&quot;});">Hacer click aqui</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="verMatch2(this,'<?php echo base64_encode($datosSolicitud['id']);?>','<?= array_implode(',', $datosSolicitud) ?>');">
```

index.php

```
$datosSolicitud = array_explode(',', $_POST['datosSolicitud']);
```